# Why xml parsing doesn't work in JQuery when working with file?

Tags: jquery, xml, html, parsing

I want to parse an xml file that exists same directory with the html file running. But it doesn't give any response when I used "data.xml". How can I fix that?

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Infos>
<Info name="Stephen" mail="example@gmail.com"/>
</Infos>
```

My code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".button").click(function () {
            var xml = "/data.xml"; //How to set path this line?
            xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
            $xml = $(xmlDoc);
            $title = $xml.find("Info");

            alert($title.text());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`var xml = "/data.xml";` creates `String` `"/data.xml"` , does not request file at location `/data.xml` at filesystem

Note also, no `.textContent` appear defined for `Info` element `alert( $title.text() );` would alert empty string.

Try using `$.ajax()` to request file from filesystem ; removing `$.parseXML()` wrapping response in `jQuery()`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".button").on('click', function () {
        var xml = "/data.xml"; //How to set path this line?

        $.ajax({
            url : xml, 
            dataType : "xml"
        }).done(function(xmlDoc) {

            var $title = $(xmlDoc).find("Info");
            // alert( $title.text() );

        }).fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             console.log(errorThrown)
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @adeneo `#document` is returned by `$.ajax()` , not `document.documentElement` ; `xmlDoc` requires wrapping in `jQuery()` to access `.find()` method https://jsfiddle.net/0L9gf12t/ , https://jsfiddle.net/0L9gf12t/1/

Comment: Well, yes, it does need wrapping, but not parsing with `$.parseXML`